# Where can I run high performance computing tasks online?

Tags: cloud, distributed-computing

I've designed and implemented a neural network in Java and need to test it with large amounts of data that I have. My laptop is unfortunately too weak for that. Is there a way to run this task online somewhere for free or a small fee?

Comment: thanks for the close vote. Can you please let me know where I should post this question?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Ubuntu in the cloud](https://try.cloud.ubuntu.com/) - if you like it and need more than one hour, you can rent instances on Amazon EC2.

Comment: Yes. So get your tests ready before running it or you would have to hurry. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some sites offering "**cloud computing**". Sounds like you'd want to rent yourself some CPU time on a cloud.

Or you could do some benchmarking on your code and see if you can get it fast enough to run on your PC.